# Copy a tile area in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, tiles

I have a canvas displaying a tile map. When scrolling, rather than refreshing the entire tile list, I want to select the useful part of the tile map that I can reuse and copy it to another canvas.

For example, if the tile map was 5 tiles across:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

And I wanted to move right (x) 1 tile... I could copy tiles 1 to 4 as these will be used in the next frame. So I would copy:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
```

I seem to be having a problem coming up with the right maths for this.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
// Calculate from and to for x and y
// Change formula if positive or negative movement
    // movX / movY = amount to move across x or y
    // (i.e. movX = 1 (right) or movX = -1 (left)
    // tileXFrom / tileYFrom = tile to start copy from
    // tileXTo / tileYTo = tile to finish copying at
if(movX > 0)
{
    tileXFrom = origX + movX;
    tileXTo = tileXFrom + (tilesCountX - movX);
}
else
{
    tileXFrom = origX;
    tileXTo = tileXFrom + (tilesCountX + movX);
}

if(movY > 0)
{
    tileYFrom = origY + movY;
    tileYTo = tileYFrom + (tilesCountY - movY);
}
else
{
    tileYFrom = origY;
    tileYTo = tileYFrom + (tilesCountY + movY);
}
```

These calculations work fine however is there a better way to do them? I'm wondering if there is a way round the positive / negative if statement.

The part where I am now stuck at is what to do to get the real x, y positions for each.

So I need to convert tile 1, 0 to an on screen x, y position in order to start the copy from there.

If that all makes sense?!

Cheers

Comment: What exactly is a tile in your context? Is it some kind of reusable object? That's how I would implement it. Using [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo), for example, it would be trivial to move (or copy) tiles from one place to another.

Comment: It is a tile map within a game loop. If the tile map has already been drawn, no point in redrawing it to the canvas so instead copy the bits already drawn across to a new canvas then just fill in the remaining tiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operators to shorten the code, but this won't change the functionality:

```
tileXFrom = (movX > 0) ? origX + movX : origX;
tileXTo   = (movX > 0) ? tileXFrom + (tilesCountX - movX) : tileXFrom + (tilesCountX + movX);
tileYFrom = (movY > 0) ? origY + movY : origY;
tileYTo   = (movY > 0) ? tileYFrom + (tilesCountY - movY) : tileYFrom + (tilesCountY + movY);
```

Comment: Thanks, they certainly look better than before. Any ideas on converting to x,y?